# Error in C: [assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]]

Tags: c, casting

I`ve this function in C, ISO C90

```
char **read_words(char *file_name);
```

But when I use it

```
char **words;
    ...
words = read_words("file.txt");
    ...
```

I've this problem

```
 main.c:72:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 words=read_words("file.txt");
      ^
```

When I debugg to see what is the problem, the function returns the adress 0x60003bbe0 but the variable 'words' takes the value 0x3bbe0, and I`ve have no idea what's the problem

Comment: you probably are missing a header include...

Comment: You need to declare `read_words` before using it, otherwise the compiler thinks it returns an `int`. Note that if your actual code looked like your question, you wouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: Thanks, that's was the problem

Comment: Post the answer and accept it rather than editing your post as "SOLVED"